# checking for regkey vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry, key

I cant get the following code to check if my regestrykey exists can  some one help. the idea is to check if it exists if so do nothing if not create it, along with its value...

the full key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VTS\Advanced Offset 2\Admin\Access

> ```
> >         If Dir$("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VTS\Advanced Offset 2\Admin", vbDirectory) <> "" Then
>
>         Else
>             MsgBox(".NET Framework 2.0")
>
>         End If
> ```

UPDATED CODE:

> ```
> Dim l_subKeyPath As String = "SOFTWARE\VTS\Advanced Offset 2\Admin\Access"
> Dim l_regKey As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(l_subKeyPath, False)
> If (l_regKey Is Nothing) Then
>     'if nothing then key doesn't exists
>     'Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VTS\Advanced Offset 2\Admin", "ACCESS", "PASSWbORD")
>     MsgBox("yess")
> Else
>     'key exists
>     MsgBox("no")
> End If
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim l_subKeyPath as string = "SOFTWARE\VTS\Advanced Offset 2\Admin\Access"
    Dim l_regKey As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(l_subKeyPath, False)
     If (l_regKey Is Nothing) Then
        'if nothing then key doesn't exists
     else
        'key exists
     End If
```

**Quoting MSDN:**

[RegistryKey.OpenSubKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx)

> If the requested key does not exist, this method returns Nothing instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: hmmm i have inserted the key and taken it out but the message box keeps telling me it exists? (see ipdated code to see whole thing)

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl: If it finds it, then it should be there.
Have tried checking manually if the key exists?
Are you using x86 or x64 machine? In case of x64, it will be under WOW64.

Answer (score 0):

You say " check if it exists if so do nothing if not create it, along with its value... ".
If you reate a key, you'll also need to create a NAME and add a value to the name, you cann't add a value to a key.

Take look at the sample in [MSDN OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z9f66s0a.aspx)